# Does the netty channel pipeline take place on the same thread?

Tags: java, multithreading, netty, logback

I am using [Netty](http://netty.io/) 4.1.3-Final with [Logback](http://logback.qos.ch/) 1.1.7, and I wish to use [MDC](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/mdc.html) to store some additional information about a client connection (IP address, client identifier, etc.) so that they can be included in the logs.

The MDC framework of Logback (and Log4J) assumes multiple threads are being used for each client, and the mapped diagnostic context is maintained on a per thread basis. This of course is not quite true in modern event-driven frameworks like Netty, which make use of asynchronous non-blocking events and reuse the same thread pool.

I was thinking of introducing 2 handlers, one which is added at the beginning of the pipeline, and adds the MDC information, and one which is added to the end of the pipeline, which then clears it. Each handler can be an inbound/outbound handler, so that it handles both inbound and outbound messages (obviously doing the opposite of each other for outbound messages, since the pipeline is invoked in reverse for outbound data in Netty.)

Is it safe to assume that the Netty channel handlers in a pipeline of the same channel are handled by the same thread?

And are they processed atomically without any chance of the same thread being used for another channel when going through the pipeline?

What if I am using a [LengthFieldBasedFrameDecoder](http://netty.io/4.1/api/io/netty/handler/codec/LengthFieldBasedFrameDecoder.html) to reassamble fragmented frames, what would happen in this case?

If this approach does not work, is there any other recommended or safer approach?  (I am considering having my handlers extend some common base handler instead which sets the MDC at the beginning of `channelRead` and removes it at the end of it, however this means that if I use other Handlers, like the Netty [ReadTimeoutHandler](http://netty.io/4.1/api/io/netty/handler/timeout/ReadTimeoutHandler.html), they won't get the MDC since it won't be set throughout the whole pipeline.)

What is the right approach to use in this case?

Comment: In my opinion, yes. When you are debugging a netty project, you'll see a single thread for every session/connection that is currently open.

As a session/connection always has it's own context, you could add the MDC  information directly to the context when `sessionOpened` gets invoked by netty.

Answer (score 0):

We came across your requirement too. Solved by transferring the map in MDC as parameter for each async call,the callee then put the passed parameters into its threadLocal MDC again! And I think within a pipeline the during execution of Netty outbound handlers can be in different thread since we use Netty as an NIO model!